# wrong code for UITableview SWIFT

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, swift, audio-player

the main role is to display the playlists names in table view, but it show me word "name" in about 500 cells!

I can make a simple errors, because i only learning swift, and it is my first programming language

There is the code:

```
import UIKit
import MediaPlayer

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

var tableData = MPMediaQuery.playlistsQuery()
var songname: NSString = MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

    self.tableView.reloadData()

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.tableData.items.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell     {

    var cell: UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel.text = songname

    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    println("Row \(indexPath.row) selected")
}
}
```

Comment: You aren't setting different texts for the cell depending on the index path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're displaying MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName in the cell which is most likely just the constant string "name"

What you need to do is set the cell's textLabel with the actual name of the playlist which would look something like this in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method

Replace

```
cell.textLabel.text = songname
```

With

```
let playlist: MPMediaPlaylist = tableData.collections[indexPath.row] as MPMediaPlaylist
let playlistName = playlist.valueForProperty(MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName) as NSString
cell.textLabel.text = playlistName;
```

Also, you need to make sure you're getting the count from the collections of the tableData so in your number of rowsInSectionMethod change:

```
return self.tableData.items.count
```

to

```
return self.tableData.collections.count
```

For A bit more understanding, what we're doing in the cellForRowAtIndexPath now is:

1. Getting a specific MPMediaPlaylist item for that particular row
2. Getting the Name of the playlist and assigning it to a variable
3. Assigning that name to the cells textLabel

Let me know if you have any other questions

Comment: this is almost work now! 22 cells are in total as it should be, but they are emty (no names)

Comment: Are you sure you've got the most updated code I posted? I edited it a few times

Comment: Oops! Sorry I just forgot to add cell.textlable ! now it is work, Thank you wery much!

Answer (score -2):

You have to cleanup the cell data since you are re-using the cells, 
Right after line

```
var cell: UITableViewCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell
```

do

```
cell.textLabel.text = ""
```

Comment: The place to reset the cell's data is in the `+prepareForReuse` method.